# Binders Design Patterns in Android - Proxy,Mediator and Bridge Pattern?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-service, android-binder

I come from C Background and have knowledge on C++(at least I know virtual functions, INheritance, Code -reuse and some OOPS concept), But still I am having hard time understanding the Design Patterns in C++/Java.I guess Binders Design Patterns are  based on C++ Design pattern(correct me).
DO i have to understand UML as well to understand them.
Plz explain or direct a link with test source code on the above.

PS: I am trying to understand this [blog](http://blog.goggb.com/?post=1580) by **Tetsuyuki Kobayashi**  and i am in no way related to him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldnt say that C++ Binders are a design pattern. I put a link [here](http://www.richelbilderbeek.nl/CppBinder.htm) explaining them.

I would also say that Design patterns arent really language specific, they can basically be implemented in any (most) programming languages. Languages that support OOP typically make implementing design patterns easier, but that could be argued.

The Gang of Four design patterns book uses UML to explain design patterns, but I wouldnt say you would have to be a UML expert to understand design patterns. If UML is bothering you, try the [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) book, its much easier to understand.